# Does using the computer before sleeping affect sleep patterns?

Tags: sleep, computers, television

According to this [Bloomberg Businessweek article](http://www.businessweek.com/lifestyle/content/healthday/650536.html) using electronics before bed may hamper sleep.

Is it true that using a computer, watching T.V. or using some other type of face-to-screen electronics before going to bed causes people to have trouble sleeping?

Comment: Skeptics is for verifying notable claims. Please edit your question such that it is asking about a notable claim, and include a source of notability.

Comment: [Welcome to the site](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! I have restricted your question to sleeping because we already have [this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/404/does-watching-television-damage-the-eyes) and [this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/does-watching-tv-make-you-stupid).

Comment: There's an overview of the research [here](http://stereopsis.com/flux/research.html), compiled by the creators of f.lux, which is software that aims to minimize the problematic sleep effects of blue light from a computer screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Make your own conclusion from the sources mentioned

This is evidence showing that using face-to-screen electronics before going to bed could harm your sleep.

- For instance, this study, published in the journal [Organizational Behavior and Human Decision Processes](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/organizational-behavior-and-human-decision-processes/) found that **smartphone use** after 9 p.m. was associated with decreased sleep quantity at night. Moreover, researchers also examined the use of other electronics -- such as desktop or laptop computers, tablets and TV -- and found similar results
- Another study from Brigham and Women's Hospital (BWH), found that:

  > [iPad readers](http://www.brighamandwomens.org/about_bwh/publicaffairs/news/pressreleases/PressRelease.aspx?sub=0&PageID=1962) had reduced secretion of melatonin, a hormone which normally rises in the evening and plays a role in inducing sleepiness".
- A [2008 study funded](http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2008-01-21/news/27697646_1_mobile-phone-radiation-phones-from-exposure-scenarios-bengt-arnetz) by major mobile manufacturers showed that people exposed to mobile radiation took more time to fall asleep and spent less time in deep sleep.
- [Another study](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/early/2013/01/08/peds.2012-1651.abstract?cited-by=yes&legid=pediatrics;peds.2012-1651v1) found that screen time before sleeping hurts sleeping cycle in young people, and concluded:

  > Screen sedentary time dominated the presleep period in this sample and was associated with a later sleep onset. **The development of interventions to reduce screen-based behaviors in the presleep period may promote earlier sleep onset and ultimately improved sleep duration in young people**.
- Another study called [ICT use and mental health in young adults](https://gupea.ub.gu.se/bitstream/2077/28245/1/gupea_2077_28245_1.pdf) found that:

  > Intensive computer use (“intensive” in terms of duration of use or continuous use without breaks) was a prospective risk factor for reporting **sleep disturbances** in the men and stress, **sleep disturbances**, and symptoms of depression in the women.
- [Another study found that teenagers who used a computer in the hour before bedtime were nearly three times as likely to get less than five hours sleep](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/11384714/Banish-smartphones-and-computers-from-bedroom-to-get-a-good-sleep-say-scientists.html)
- To make the evidence definitive, a study published in nature [Perspective: Casting light on sleep deficiency](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v497/n7450_supp/full/497S13a.html) found  that:

  > **The use of electric lights at night is disrupting the sleep of more and more people.**
- A [Harvard report](http://hms.harvard.edu/news/e-readers-foil-good-nights-sleep) examined some research and confirmed that reading light-emitting e-books before bed, like computer tablets, **could have a detrimental effect on sleep**, which can in turn lead to serious health problems:

  > During the two-week inpatient study, **twelve participants read digital books on an iPad for four hours before bedtime each night** for five consecutive nights. This was repeated with printed books. The order was randomized with some reading on the iPad first and others reading the printed book first. Participants reading on the iPad took longer to fall asleep, were less sleepy in the evening and spent less time in REM sleep. **They had reduced secretion of melatonin, a hormone that normally rises in the evening and plays a role in inducing sleepiness. Additionally, iPad readers had a delayed circadian rhythm, indicated by melatonin levels, of more than an hour.** Participants who read on the iPad were less sleepy before bedtime but were sleepier and less alert the following morning after eight hours of sleep. **Although iPads were used in this study, researchers also measured other devices that emit blue light, including eReaders, laptops, cell phones and LED monitors.**

Comment: Professor Russell Foster of Oxford-https://www.rsb.org.uk/images/pdf/russell-foster.pdf had previously downplayed concerns about electronic devices and melatonin levels, stating that melatonin levels are not a good way to predict how much sleep someone will get. "There is no empirical evidence that suggests that lower levels of melatonin will have a direct effect on the sleep axis. Making the jump from the biology of what we know of melatonin to the effect it's having on sleep is completely flawed"

Comment: Almost all the studies you cite are about correlation, but your summary is about causation. You must distinguish the two. Secondly, the strongest study you cite is the last, but it's based on 12 participants: it's not "overwhelming" evidence by any stretch.

Comment: This comment thread is getting a bit too personal, everyone please try to focus on the subject and not the involved users.

Comment: A Nature Perspective is more like a news article, it is not a peer-reviewed paper and not a study.

Comment: The third 2008 study has different claims from the funding body of the study. "The study had been funded by the Mobile Manufacturers Forum (MMF), which is made up of industry giants like Nokia and Motorola. A spokesperson for the forum told British newspaper The Independent that the "results were inconclusive", and that "the researchers did not claim that exposure caused sleep disturbance"."

Comment: I think you might be overplaying the "Correlation, not causation" level here. We do have a pretty well understood mechanism through which electronics directly effect this sleep hormone, melatonin. Which I think is the one area where this question could be improved: focus more on the underlying theory (does melatonin indeed effect sleep [http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11941/]). Then ergo, we have plausible causation. Which matches the experimental results you have supplied already.

Comment: Well, as the bounty initiator, I'm satisfied by the answer. It is obviously not possible to draw certain causation, but it is plausible enough with current science - when I first heard about this I was skeptic that a) somebody has actually found lower melatonin levels associates with the use of screens and b) that use of screens would be associated with less sleep QUALITY (not quantity, because that could be just because the person enjoys reading/playing and stays awake longer). Of course, 12 people is a small n, needs replication, but beeing crossover (sort of) adds a little value. Nice.